# Google Colab does not show image

Tags: python, opencv, yolo

I am using YOLO for object detection. When I run the following code in Google Colab shows the image but when I save the code in a py file it does not show the image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import core.utils as utils
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image

return_elements = ["input/input_data:0", "pred_sbbox/concat_2:0", "pred_mbbox/concat_2:0", "pred_lbbox/concat_2:0"]
pb_file         = "./yolov3_coco.pb"
image_path      = "./docs/images/road.jpeg"
num_classes     = 80
input_size      = 416
graph           = tf.Graph()

original_image = cv2.imread(image_path)
original_image = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
original_image_size = original_image.shape[:2]
image_data = utils.image_preporcess(np.copy(original_image), [input_size, input_size])
image_data = image_data[np.newaxis, ...]

return_tensors = utils.read_pb_return_tensors(graph, pb_file, return_elements)


with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    pred_sbbox, pred_mbbox, pred_lbbox = sess.run(
        [return_tensors[1], return_tensors[2], return_tensors[3]],
                feed_dict={ return_tensors[0]: image_data})

pred_bbox = np.concatenate([np.reshape(pred_sbbox, (-1, 5 + num_classes)),
                            np.reshape(pred_mbbox, (-1, 5 + num_classes)),
                            np.reshape(pred_lbbox, (-1, 5 + num_classes))], axis=0)

bboxes = utils.postprocess_boxes(pred_bbox, original_image_size, input_size, 0.3)
bboxes = utils.nms(bboxes, 0.45, method='nms')
image = utils.draw_bbox(original_image, bboxes)
image = Image.fromarray(image)
image # image works but image.show() does not work.
```

I also tried to use

```
cv2_imshow(image)
```

but it did not work. In this case, it throws the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'clip'
```

In case of using image.show() does not throw any error but it does not show the image and the bounding boxes!

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

First, since you are using `Pillow` to read in the image, you probably should use it for `show`:

```
im = Image.open(path)
im.show()
```

I am sure it will work on Jupyter, since `PIL.show()` calls an external program to display the image, after storing it in a temporary file. In your case, I would suggest doing this way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This works for Jupyter!  Let's assume that we saved the above code in py file. if we call that file inJjupyter notebook. it does not work! Do you have any suggestions!

Comment: @Naik, `%matplotlib inline` is specified for Jupiter, so I don't think it will work, plus you are using colab, if you run the script and there's no way colab will open an image viewing app from the website. You have to copy and paste your code in the cell. However, there might be ways you can 'hack' the Jupiter, but I don't think it worths it.

Answer (score 0):

Save the notebook in .ipynb format, whenever you load this file again - the plots will be visible.